# IIS7+ Status Code 500 0 64

Tags: php, iis, 500-error

We run a webapplication and switched from Apache/PHP to IIS/PHP(fastcgi). Now our client gets like 200 blank pages a day. According to the IIS logs it's "500 0 64". The sc-win32-status 64 is "The specified network name is no longer available".

This sounds like a network problem but according to our client the network should be fine and that's not our part. We didn't have those problems with Apache/PHP.

Is there any way to find the cause? Eventlog doesn't show anything and we don't have any errors inside the php_errors.log.

Server is Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter if that matters. Application is used in LAN only.

Comment: Review the %WinDir%\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR logs for clues as to what the Windows HTTP service thinks the disconnect is.